# Kubernetes External Access Of A Single Pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am running a kubernetes cluster in AWS. I have 2 nodes. I have one pod that should be accessible externally. The problem is, that pod can be on either node.

The solution according to the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/):

1. Expose the deployment as a `NodePort` service.
2. `get pods` to find the name of the node running the pod.
3. `get nodes` to find the IP address of the named node.
4. Open the `NodePort` port through EC2 Security Group.

The problem here is that this pod could be restarted/switch nodes, I think? At that point the application will be unavailable by the previous node IP address.

How can I make sure an application is always available, even if this specific pod switches nodes during a restart/etc?

Note: I definitely only want one of this specific pod. I do not want replicas.

Comment: You misunderstood what is verification and what is configuration. The doc tells your to use a node port, the external IP is your duty and problem and very specific to how you did configure things. What you have to do is add the same security group to both nodes allowing input to the nodeport of your service, how you load balance above nodes is your choices of infrastructure. (or you'll need an ingress controller somewhere)

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai. I am very naive in networking concepts. I was under the impression a load balancer would distribute the load between my 2 nodes. But this pod will ever only be available on one node at a time. Can a load balancer account for this?

Comment: If you haev an ELB in front of your nodes with a proper healthcheck yes.

Comment: Cool! Beyond writing a book, is it possible to tell me at a high level when to use ingress vs elb?

Comment: @rys ELB could take virtually infinite load before a distribution to nodes and make configuration simple, but has it's own pricing and limited customization.
Ingress controllers work inside cluster so they take additional resourses to work, need some extra treatment in DNS to distribute load, have more capabilities in configuration and most of them are free to use.

Comment: @rys the book is already written and is kubernetes documentation, I agree it is not simple, but running a k8s cluster is running a datacenter and _really_ needs reading books, not just 1 but many. It can't fit in an answer here IMHO

Comment: @chupasaurus free to use in license cost, far from free in compute ressources and even less free in term of knowledge, you need to learn and spend time on them, human resources and learning have a cost also.

Comment: @Tensibai Of course, but I've covered these points "at a high level", as was asked.

Comment: @chupasaurus this part is so overlooked I felt it was necessary to complete :)

Answer (score 3):

The `NodePort` will resolve correctly, no matter the node where the pods is (even if it gets rescheduled on a different node).

Any `<Node IP>:<NodePort>` will resolve to a `Service` type `NodePort`, no matter what node the pods are running.

Every node will forward traffic to that port to the `Service`.

You need to be on the same network (or create a SSH tunnel) or open that port in one of your nodes to the world.

Comment: Right that is the problem I am describing - the specific Node-IP is needed externally. If my 1 pod is on Node-1 and I use Node-1-IP, then all is good. If I restart/update the pod and it is now on Node-2 then Node-1-IP I am using in my scripts will no longer work. So that is the problem - I want to access this single pod externally by IP, whether it is at Node-1-IP or Node-2-IP

Comment: @rys that sounds strange for a k8s service in node port exposition, each node should route to the pod, wherever it is (that's omitting advanced network filtering but I doubt you are at this point). In raw case talking to any node on NodePort should redirect to the pod with more or less obscure redirects, explaining all in details would be rewriting k8s doc sadly and not fitting the format of this site

Comment: Oh so you mean, a pod on `Node-1` with `NodePort` `12345` should render 
 *externally* from both `Node-1-IP:12345` and `Node-2-IP:12345`, even without a load balancer?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what should be happening

Comment: Weird, I have tried with the 2 external IPs and only one works.

Comment: Are you sure that you have opened the port to external traffic on both nodes?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to put some concreteness to @Tensibai's recommendation in the comments. I began looking into Ingress and Ingress controllers, but my knowledge/implementation was wrong. I successfully connected via an Ingress, but I felt, at least my implementation, it still depended on the node the ingress was running on.

So, I began looking at ELB on AWS. I couldn't find any good tutorials on implementing this specific for AWS. The official [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/load-balance-access-application-cluster/) actually helped more than I was aware. It ended up being embarrassingly easy. I made a single change to my service yaml:

```
type: NodePort
```

to

```
type: LoadBalancer
```

and applied it via `kubectl apply -f my-file.yaml`

You can then find the external IP:

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP        PORT(S)
my-service       LoadBalancer   100.99.98.97    12.34.56.78        444:31415/TCP
```

One part I was not expecting is that the first port `444` is used, rather than the NodePort (`31415` in my case).

To access my app I would use: `12.34.56.78:444`

The second part I was not expecting is that the external IP, in my case on AWS, was an ELB. It was created automatically in AWS. I am not sure if kubernetes does this, or kops? Maybe someone can clarify in the comments.

Comment: Yes kops on aws does some magic as such defining a load balancer does configure an ELB to target the correct nodes, from memory I'm unsure if it spin up a new ELB or if it modify a pre-existing one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the feature of port-forward using kubectl,

```
Examples:
  # Listen on ports 5000 and 6000 locally, forwarding data to/from ports 5000 and 6000 in the pod
  kubectl port-forward pod/mypod 5000 6000

  # Listen on ports 5000 and 6000 locally, forwarding data to/from ports 5000 and 6000 in a pod selected by the
deployment
  kubectl port-forward deployment/mydeployment 5000 6000

  # Listen on port 8888 locally, forwarding to 5000 in the pod
  kubectl port-forward pod/mypod 8888:5000

  # Listen on a random port locally, forwarding to 5000 in the pod
  kubectl port-forward pod/mypod :5000
```

But if you want to expose your pod, so that other pods can communicate to it, use services. 
[K8s service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)